# Converting strings to date and time and extract year, month, day, day of week, hour and minutes

Tags: android

I am retrieving JSON objects to my Android app. They have two fields: `date` and `time`.
On a layout I need to extract from these two fields the following strings:

> 1. Day of week (e.g. Monday)
> 2. Day of the month (e.g. 21)
> 3. Month (e.g. April)
> 4. Year (e.g. 2014)
> 5. Hour (e.g. 17)
> 6. Minutes (e.g. 35)

The fields are `date="2014-04-21"`, `time="17:35:00"`

How could I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a class SimpleDateFormat that parses the date and time you specifiend

Here is an example from your problems:

---

```
    String string = "2014-04-21 17:35:00";
    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    calender.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-d k:m:s").parse(string));
    System.out.println("Day of week: " + calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)); //2 is monday
    System.out.println("Day of the month: " + calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    System.out.println("Month: " + calender.get(Calendar.MONTH)); //0 is january 3 is april
    System.out.println("Year: " + calender.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    System.out.println("Hour: " + calender.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    System.out.println("Minutes: " + calender.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

Where the string is the string result from your json

Comment: Good Your answer is better.

Comment: @user3444777, I have changed the time format to kk:mm:ss, but the hour is shown as 5, not as 17 like I need.

Comment: @mvasco updated try to do it again using the above code

Comment: @mvasco there is a little hack that changes the 12 hours format to 24 hour format just change the Calendar.HOUR to Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking that date and time are separated by space.
Use this:

```
    String dateString = "2014-09-13 17:35:00";
    String part[] = dateString.split(" ");
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date formattedDate;
    try {
        formattedDate = (Date) format.parse(part[0]);


        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(formattedDate);

        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH); // Month
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);// Day of the month
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int day_of_week = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        String time[] = part[1].split(":");
        // Your desired values are in time[0], time[1], time[2]


    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```